# How to replace the values/text in XML file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, xml

I have the following content in a XML file. I'm trying to update the XML file using powershell script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Topology>
  <Core>
    <SERVER1 desc="computer name server"></SERVER1>
    <SERVER2 desc="computer name server"></SERVER2>
    <CORE1 desc="application core"></CORE1>
    <CORE2 desc="application core"></CORE2>
  </Core>
    <Credentials>
          <AppCredentials>
              <USERNAME></USERNAME>
              <PASSWORD></PASSWORD>
          </AppCredentials>
          <ServicesCredentials>
              <SC_USERNAME></SC_USERNAME>
              <SC_PASSWORD></SC_PASSWORD>
              <SC_DOMAIN></SC_DOMAIN>
          </ServicesCredentials>
    </Credentials>
</Topology>
```

I have written the following so that the XML file will get updated. However, it is not working as expected.

```
$xmldata =[XML](Get-Content C:\Config.xml)
$xmldata. Core.SERVER1.InnerText = 'Admin'
$xmldata. Core.SERVER2.InnerText = 'Nimda'
$xmldata. AppCredentials.USERNAME.InnerText = 'Account'
$xmldata. AppCredentialsPASSWORD.InnerText = '123'
$xmldata. Save((Resolve-Path C:\Config.xml). Path)
```

I have received the following error.

The property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\replacetokendistributedtest.ps1:2 char:1

- $xmldata. Core.SERVER2.InnerText = 'Nimda'
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

Finally, the XML file should look like as below when we run the above script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Topology>
  <Core>
    <SERVER1 desc="computer name server">Admin</SERVER1>
    <SERVER2 desc="computer name server">Nimda</SERVER2>
    <CORE1 desc="application core"></CORE1>
    <CORE2 desc="application core"></CORE2>
  </Core>
    <Credentials>
          <AppCredentials>
              <USERNAME>Account</USERNAME>
              <PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD>
          </AppCredentials>
          <ServicesCredentials>
              <SC_USERNAME></SC_USERNAME>
              <SC_PASSWORD></SC_PASSWORD>
              <SC_DOMAIN></SC_DOMAIN>
          </ServicesCredentials>
    </Credentials>
</Topology>
```

Please let me know any additional changes are required for this to work

Comment: Why use PowerHell? `It is not working as expected` Ok, what happened?

Comment: Updated the error in the post

Comment: And what happens if you use this workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218913

Comment: [It’s very apparent that very little research has been performed on your part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268865/powershell-cant-set-inner-text-of-xmlelement). InnerText isn’t proper PowerShell syntax. Voting to throw this to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xmldata = [XML](Get-Content C:\temp\config.xml)
$xmldata.Topology.Core.SERVER1.desc = 'Admin'
$xmldata.Topology.Core.SERVER2.desc = 'Nimda'
$xmldata.Topology.Credentials.AppCredentials.USERNAME = 'Account'
$xmldata.Topology.Credentials.AppCredentials.PASSWORD = '123'
$xmldata. Save("C:\temp\Config.xml")
```

But it's not a secure way, cause credentials are in clear text in a simple text file (a xml file is a text file).

Regards

Comment: +1 from me. I don't know why you got down-voted when your code works fine.